# Sort a table with another table inside it

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table

I currently have a table with a another table inside it that I have appended dynamically, for example:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Institute</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>MIT</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Name</th>
                    <th>Age</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>David</td>
                    <td>21</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>James</td>
                    <td>19</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>UBC</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th>Age</th>
                    <th>Height</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Angela</th>
                    <th>18</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>Peter</th>
                    <th>23</th>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    <tr>
```

I used a javascript table sorting function from w3schools and it works well:

```
function sortTable(tableId, valueType, column) {
    var table, rows, switching, i, x, y, shouldSwitch;
    table = document.getElementById(tableId);
    switching = true;

    while (switching) {

        switching = false;
        rows = table.rows;

        for (i = 1; i < (rows.length - 1); i++) {

            shouldSwitch = false;

            x = rows[i].$("TD")[column];
            console.log("x: " + x);
            y = rows[i + 1].$("TD")[column];

            if (valueType == "String") {
                if (x.innerHTML.toLowerCase() > y.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (valueType == "Integer") {
                if (parseInt(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) < parseInt(y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            } else if (valueType == "IntegerReverse") {
                if (parseInt(x.innerHTML.toLowerCase()) > parseInt(y.innerHTML.toLowerCase())) {
                    shouldSwitch = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (shouldSwitch) {

            rows[i].parentNode.insertBefore(rows[i + 1], rows[i]);
            switching = true;
        }
    }
}
```

However, the problem is when I sort the table, the outer table sorts fine but the inner table gets messed up. I tried to give the inner table's parent td an id and tried to use the 'not' operator but I think because I am mixing jQuery with javascript, it still doesn't work.

Does anyone know how to sort just the outer table and keep the inner table as it is while still being appends to its parent td? Any help is much appreciated! ^^

Thank you!

Comment: Can you give me the piece of the code you are running to sort it (not the function, but how you call it)

Comment: I added an image next to the outer table's header row (th) which when clicked, has an onClick function directly on the img tag.

 "<th>Rank<img src='images/sort.svg' onClick='sortTable(\"player_table\",\"Integer\",0)'></th>"